# store indexes from a table in R

Tags: r, indexing

I need some help in here.

I have a table with multiple columns. One varying from 1 to 30 and another from 1 to 6. The other columns have multiple values. What I need is to store the indexes for value 1 from the 1st column and 1 from the 2nd column, value 1 for the first column and 2 from the 2nd column and so fourth... value 2 from the 1st column, value 2 for the 2nd column and so fourth till I have all the indexes.

Thank you in advance

Comment: This is unclear ... so make an example with a smaller number of columns and post the code to construct. One question would be whether it really were an R "table" which is really a matrix -like object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 'which' function to get indexes:

```
y = sample(1:6, 30, replace=T)
x = sample(1:30, 30, replace=T)

df = data.frame(x,y)
head(df)
   x y
1 22 1
2 13 5
3 28 4
4 28 3
5  7 3
6 30 6

which(df$x==2)
[1] 16 22
which(df$y==2)
[1] 10 11 12 18 21 27
```

You can use simple 'for' loop to do multiple tests:

```
for(i in 1:6){
    cat("indexes of",i,"in x:\n")
    print(which(df$x==i))
    cat("indexes of",i,"in y:\n")
    print(which(df$y==i))
    cat("\n")
}

indexes of 1 in x:
integer(0)
indexes of 1 in y:
[1]  1  9 14 19 24 26

indexes of 2 in x:
[1] 16 22
indexes of 2 in y:
[1] 10 11 12 18 21 27

indexes of 3 in x:
integer(0)
indexes of 3 in y:
[1]  4  5 17

indexes of 4 in x:
integer(0)
indexes of 4 in y:
[1]  3  7 13 20 23 28

indexes of 5 in x:
[1] 23
indexes of 5 in y:
[1]  2 15 16 29 30

indexes of 6 in x:
integer(0)
indexes of 6 in y:
[1]  6  8 22 25
```

For all columns:

```
for(i in 1:6) {for(j in 1:ncol(df)) {cat("indexes of",i,"in",names(df)[j],'\n'); print(which(df[[j]]==i))} ;cat('\n')}

indexes of 1 in x 
integer(0)
indexes of 1 in y 
[1]  1  9 14 19 24 26
...
```

Comment: You should click on upvote / tick and accept the answer.